# Flash CS6 launch fail when incorporating ANE

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-cs6

I've been trying to "install" an .ane-file in Flash CS6 for some time now.
When testing the app in flash I get an alert saing "Test movie launch failed" and then the output sais:

> Native Extensions: file:///C:/Users/Martin/AppData/Local/Temp/Tmp_ANE_File_Unzipped_Packages/AdMob.ane ignored because directory does not contain an extension.xml file file:///C:/Users/Martin/AppData/Local/Temp/Tmp_ANE_File_Unzipped_Packages/AdMob.ane/META-INF/ANE/extension.xml
>
> The content cannot be loaded because there was a problem loading an extension: Error: Requested extension com.pozirk.ads.AdMob could not be found.

And when I test it on my device (android) it's just a blank screen.

I've been trying it out with these: StickSports/MoPub-ANE, digicrafts/MoPub-ANE and pozirk/ANEAdMob. But non seem to work for me. I've imported the ane the right way (in the actionscript settings --> library path). I've updated the AIR sdk to the latest. I've included the extensions in the xxx-app.xlm file. And I'm pretty sure that my actionscript is fine and the the import paths to the as-scripts correct.

I've also tried creating a ios-app version, same error message there (haven't tested that on a device yet though). If I remove the imported .ane from the file other errors show up. And I've tried to add the .swc instead, and then the error massages go away (on one of the extensions, but not on one of the other three) - but on the device, the screen is still blank.

It must be something easy that I'm missing (can only find one result on google with this error, but it doesn't give me anything). Is this message supposed to be here? Have I missed something on the MoPub and/or the AdMob homepages? What can be wrong? Please help. =)

Comment: Flash CS6 works with AIR 3.2 by default. Did you update to newer versions?

Comment: Yes, I did. I read a thread somewhere saying that could be the problem.

Comment: I managed to remove this error by extracting the ane (with winrar). Take out the META-INF directory and copy it to the C:/Users/Martin/AppData/Local/Temp/Tmp_ANE_File_Unzipped_Packages/AdMob.ane directory. But that probably wasn't the problem. I got it to work on my device now, for some reason, but if I remove the files from the just discussed directory, it still works. But only the pozirk ANE work, cannot get StickSports to work. :-(

Comment: Now everything works, even for sportsticks extension which I think I prefer to use. Had to make some adjustments on the mobup and admob websites as well as change the -app.xml file to match the -app.xml file in the example folder from sticksports.

Comment: But still, every time I restart flash I have to add those files into that directory if I want it to work when testing the flashmovie. Is there a workaround???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to tell you ,if you want fix your problem,you need to update flash ide ,air sdk and admob ane.

1.install flash cc,it easy to use ane in flash cc ,not need unzip ane any more.

2.update air sdk to 14( http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html ),old version air not been support by ios any more

3.download the new version admob ane( https://github.com/lilili87222/admob-for-flash ),old version ane not been support by google play any more.